# Refresh page with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a button on a page1 which opens a new page2 in the existing window. When page2 is closed i want page1 to be refreshed.

It should be said that page1 is not the parent of page2 even though the button is triggered from page1.

Comment: page1 is the opener of page2 ?

Comment: by new page you mean a new tab or browser window?

Comment: Post your code, it will help us.

Comment: Is this page2 opens as a popup window?

Comment: So your button.... is a link?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the 2nd window using javascript and set an interval to see if it is closed. When it is closed you can then refresh your page.

```
// Code goes here
var childWindow;
var timer;
function openWindow() {
  childWindow = window.open('http://google.com','','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
  timer = setInterval(checkChild, 500);
}

function checkChild() {
  if(childWindow && childWindow.closed) {
    alert("Child window closed");  
    clearInterval(timer);
    window.location.reload();
  }
};
```

Comment: The above answers did not solve the issue. Let me try to explain it in another way: I have a page1 called "https://aaa". On page1 i have a button. When i click this button it opens a new page2 in a new window called "https://bbb". It is not me who creates the script that opens page2, it happens from the system. If i try to make a window.location.reload(); it opens link "https://ccc" so window.location. reload do not recognize page1's url.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, it should work

```
function buttonClick(url){

newWindow=window.open(url);

newWindow.onunload=function{ window.location.reload();};

}
```

Note: onunload event works only in IE and Firefox

Comment: The above answers did not solve the issue. Let me try to explain it in another way: I have a page1 called "aaa";. On page1 i have a button. When i click this button it opens a new page2 in a new window called "bbb";. It is not me who creates the script that opens page2, it happens from the system. If i try to make a window.location.reload(); it opens link "ccc"; so window.location. reload do not recognize page1's url.

Comment: Here is my code if it can help:  function fonunload( {
                  
                  
                       window.close();
                       
                       var id = getParam("va_Call_ID");
                       var url1 = 'https://' + getDomain() + '.salesforce.com/' + id;
                       var win = window.open(url1);
                       win.location.reload();
               
                                                    
                   }
                     
     
        <body  onunload="fonunload()" >
           
        </body>

Comment: from your code, you are not reloading the window 'aaa', instead you are closing window 'aaa' and opening a new window(url1) and reloading that newly opened window